# Laravel 4: package database seed

Tags: php, laravel-4

In package, we are able to put our migration files in `vendor/package/src/migrations` and run it via `php artisan migrate --bench="vendor/package"`

But where to put and how to run the database seed from a package?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

The migrations and seeding docs are here http://laravel.com/docs/migrations 
Seeding is at the bottom of the page.

Basically you make a new file in the apps/database/seeds folder and extend the Seeder class.

You then call it from the apps/database/seeds/DatabaseSeeder.php file in the run function

```
public function run()
{
    Eloquent::unguard();

    $this->call('UserTableSeeder');
}
```

Then you run the db:seed command after you've migrated your database.

```
php artisan db:seed
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Yes, I do understand how to create and use seed normal way. But I don't know how to do it into my custom package. I mean my package will come with migration & seed file. Once user install it, they just run migration & seed. Then, everything is up and running.

Comment: I'm sorry, I didn't read your question correctly. I haven't used a seed in a package yet so I can't answer that.

Comment: Apparently there's an update on the way which will publish migrations from your packages into your app's main migrations directory.  I'm not sure if they're also planning on doing the same with seeds.

Comment: Hey, I don't know if you still need this but judging by the way https://github.com/laravel/cashier does it. They make a migration with a custom artisan command.